# How is installing linux packages via apt-get different from building and compiling from source?

Tags: linux

I've heard a lot of people say that building/compiling from source gives you optimized performance, since the compiler is able to fine tune the performance to the system.

On the other hand, installing the package is also supported by package managers like `apt-get`, which also show the message at time that they are downloading the sources and compiling them.

So what is the difference between the two in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is:

- When you take source code and compile it on you system, you can make the results more adapted to your system, using flags during the compilation process to make it aware of your CPU, GPU, existing libraries, etc.
- A downloaded binary has been compiled to work on most environments, so it is not optimized for specific environments.

Comment: So basically, when we install via the apt-get way, are we using a pre-compiled binary for the target platform?

Comment: That's right. That's the cause you can't use any repository but the one adjusted for your version. On *Ubuntu* they use names as `pangolin` or `quetzal` to  help to identify which repository your system must use. Remember that you can issue `apt-get source`to download source code from *apt-get*.

Answer (score 1):

When you are compiling from source, you download the source code from a Github repo or a website, you unpack it, run ./configure, make, make install. I'll explain the commands:

`./configure` checks for dependencies, if you have certain libraries installed etc. and adds certain lines to the build configuration.

`make` actually makes the binaries from the source code using the configuration provided by "./configure".

Finally `make install` installs the binaries to your PC.

When you use `apt-get` to install apps, it downloads already compiled binaries, and installs them to your PC.

You can use `apt-get` to download source code and you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: And if you actually tuned the compiler to fit the underlying hardware you could benefit from compiling from source. I wonder if anyone actually does that.

Comment: I guess it's mainly because of modifying the code to fit certain purposes.